# Keyboard input stops working in Swing application (a calculator) after clicking on a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, calculator, keylistener

I'm making a calculator using Swing. So far I have created a GUI that consists of a JFrame with BorderLayout, and in its center I put a JPanel that has a JLabel (representing the screen of the calculator) and some JButtons (representing the keys).

I want the calculator to be able to receive input directly from the keyboard, so I included the method addKeyListener in a class that extends JFrame and I put as an argument a reference to an object of a class that implements KeyListener.

When I run the application it accepts keyboard input until I click on one of the JButtons. After that using the keyboard doesn't work anymore.

I suspect the problem is about focus, but it is not a problem that I could fix by clicking anywhere on the application. I added the following code:

```
setFocusable(true);
```

to the JFrame but it did not help. I have read that using Key Bindings maybe a better option than using a KeyListener, but I am not really sure about this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing components are *lightweight* and use [`KeyBindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), where `KeyListener`s are for AWT components which are *heavyweight*. and known to have focus issues when mixed with Swing components. Thus I suggest changing to `KeyBindings` (but I see you have heard of them). You would use them something like:

```
final JButton b=..;

//method to add keybindings to a JComponent ie JButton,JPanel,JTextField etc
private void addKeyBindings(JComponent jc) {

    //not the getInputMap(..) call it could also be JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED etc
    jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "D pressed");

    jc.getActionMap().put("D pressed", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //do something when d is pressed
            b.doClick();
        }
    });
}
```

For general knowledge a very hacky solution would be calling `requestFocusInWindow()` on the component to which the listeners are attached whenever focus is lost (like after button click etc)

Comment: `//do something when d is pressed` == required to add `JButton#doClick()`

Comment: @mKorbel very true +1 added it

Comment: Technically, `KeyListener` isn't restricted to heavyweight components, but it DOES suffer from focus issues - ie the registered component MUST have focus in order to receive key events, which the key bindings API can be used to overcome.  However, +1 for the key bindings use

Comment: Thank you very much. I decided to use your "hacky solution" because it was much simpler for me. Thanks also for the explanation on KeyBindings.

Answer (score 1):

It's another hacky approach, but you could alter the properties of the JButton when you create it so that it can't take the focus in the first place i.e:

```
myJbutton.setFocusable(false);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: not an overly good idea: that makes the button inaccessible by keyboard, thus violating usability best-practices (all interaction must be possible by mouse and keyboard)